# Plugins not called in magento 2

Tags: magento2, plugin

I have created a plugin in my custom module to override the default method `getName()` in `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product.php`

I've created my custom module named `Firstmodule` inside `app\code\Magento`. I am using the `after` listener of plugins.

The file `app\code\Magento\Firstmodule\etc\frontend\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="Magento_Firstmodule::before" type="Magento\Firstmodule\Model\Basic" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

And the Model `app\code\Magento\Firstmodule\Model\Basic.php`

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Firstmodule\Model;

class Plugin {

    public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        return '|' . $result . '|';
    }
}
```

Still there is no result on the frontend product view page.

Can anyone tell me what is missing.? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have specified a type of Magento\Firstmodule\Model\Basic but called the class 'Plugin' in your Basic.php file. It needs to be

```
class Basic {
}
```